# SQL Get values from other tables before Insert Into query command

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am wanting to create a query that allows me to look up a number that's presented in another table before I add that ID's name to the needed table being called by the query.

An example:

> Table1

```
ID   |name   |nameID |network |...
----------------------------------
5    |Bob    |4      |NPOW    |...
6    |Billy  |8      |BGER    |...
```

> Table2

```
ID   |name   |nameID |network |...
----------------------------------
3    |Stan   |2      |ERFDT   |...
```

> Table3

```
ID   |name   |nameID |network |...
----------------------------------
3    |Steve  |3      |FRVS    |...
```

> Table4 (The table I am inserting the new rows below into)

```
ID   |name   |nameID |network |...
----------------------------------
```

On my page these are the new values I need to add to the **table4** above:

```
Name   |ID |network |...
------------------------
Nick   |4  |RFGH    |...
Tony   |3  |ESLO    |...
James  |2  |HUII    |...
Rusty  |3  |ERNM    |...
```

Now what I am wanting to do is see what column **ID** **equals X** and place that name into **Table4**.

So doing that the outcome for **table4** should look like this **after the insert**:

```
ID   |name   |nameFromID |network |...
--------------------------------------
1    |Nick   |Bob        |RFGH    |...
2    |Tony   |Steve      |ESLO    |...
3    |James  |Stan       |HUII    |...
4    |Rusty  |Steve      |ERNM    |...
```

So what would the **INSERT INTO Table4** **query** look like for doing this?

Comment: Is nameID unique in tables 1-3? Can a nameID like 3 be in more than 1 table?

Comment: Yes it can, @dfundako

Comment: Then what do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a view, some joins, and a temp table or some other staging table with session scoping. Here's a temp table approach.

The view to bring all the different tables into a single queryable form:

```
CREATE VIEW vAllNames
AS
SELECT [Name], NameID FROM Table1 UNION
SELECT [Name], NameID FROM Table2 UNION
SELECT [Name], NameID FROM Table3
```

The above assumes that `NameId` cannot be duplicated across these tables, so I've used `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`. Otherwise you'll need to tell us how you want the name to resolve when the id matches successfully to multiple tables. Would you want multiple records inserted into table 4, only the first match, some kind of concatenation, etc.

The temp table so we have something to select from for the insertion unless you want to insert one at a time (you could also do this with a session scoped persistent table or something along those lines):

```
CREATE TABLE #TempDataToInsert
(
    [Name] NVARCHAR(256),
    ID INT,
    network CHAR(4)
)
```

Once you've created those you can insert the data from your page directly into `TempDataToInsert`. Once your data is staged there you can run the final `insert into`:

```
INSERT INTO Table4
    ([Name], nameFromID, network) -- Assumes ID is an identity column
SELECT
    tempData.[Name], allNames.[Name], tempData.network
FROM
    #TempDataToInsert tempData
    LEFT OUTER JOIN vAllNames allNames ON tempData.ID = allNames.NameID -- assumes no match is still valid for insertions
```

You'll need to clean up the temp table afterwards and I've made some assumptions about your schema but this should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp0
(
    ID INT,
    [Name] VARCHAR(100),
    NameId INT,
    Network VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO #Temp0
(
    ID,
    Name,
    NameId,
    Network
)
VALUES
(5, 'Bob', 4, 'NPOW'),
(6, 'Billy', 8, 'BGER');

CREATE TABLE #Temp1
(
    ID INT,
    [Name] VARCHAR(100),
    NameId INT,
    Network VARCHAR(100)
);
INSERT INTO #Temp1
(
    ID,
    Name,
    NameId,
    Network
)
VALUES
(3, 'Stan', 2, 'ERFDT');
CREATE TABLE #Temp2
(
    ID INT,
    [Name] VARCHAR(100),
    NameId INT,
    Network VARCHAR(100)
);
INSERT INTO #Temp2
(
    ID,
    Name,
    NameId,
    Network
)
VALUES
(3, 'Steve', 3, 'FRVS');
SELECT *
INTO #Temp
FROM
(
    SELECT [Name],
           NameId
    FROM #Temp0
    UNION
    SELECT [Name],
           NameId
    FROM #Temp1
    UNION
    SELECT [Name],
           NameId
    FROM #Temp2
) AS Temp;



CREATE TABLE #Temp3
(
    [Name] VARCHAR(100),
    Id INT,
    Network VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO #Temp3
(
    Name,
    Id,
    Network
)
VALUES
('Nick', 4, 'RFGH'),
('Tony', 3, 'ESLO'),
('James', 2, 'HUII'),
('RUSTY', 3, 'ERNM');


CREATE TABLE #Table4
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    [Name] VARCHAR(100),
    NameFormId VARCHAR(100),
    Network VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO #Table4
SELECT T2.Name,
       T1.Name,
       T2.Network
FROM #Temp T1
    JOIN #Temp3 T2
        ON T1.NameId = T2.Id;

SELECT *
FROM #Table4;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following code demonstrates how to match data on `NameId` between tables. It assumes that the `Name`s being added are unique. If there are multiple `NameId` matches between input tables then the earliest match is given preference. Multiple `NameId` matches within a single input table give preference to the lowest `Id`.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Table1 as Table ( Id Int, Name VarChar(10), NameId Int, Network VarChar(10) );
insert into @Table1 ( Id, Name, NameId, Network ) values
  ( 5, 'Bob', 4, 'NPOW' ), ( 6, 'Billy', 8, 'BGER' );
select * from @Table1;

declare @Table2 as Table ( Id Int, Name VarChar(10), NameId Int, Network VarChar(10) );
insert into @Table2( Id, Name, NameId, Network ) values
  ( 3, 'Stan', 2, 'ERFDT' );
select * from @Table2;

declare @Table3 as Table ( Id Int, Name VarChar(10), NameId Int, Network VarChar(10) );
insert into @Table3 ( Id, Name, NameId, Network ) values
  ( 3, 'Steve', 3, 'FRVS' ),
  ( 4, 'Steven', 3, 'FRVS' ), -- Note duplicate   NameId   value.
  ( 9, 'Stanley', 2, 'VOOT' ); -- Note duplicate   NameId   value.
select * from @Table3;

declare @ValuesToAdd as Table ( Name VarChar(10), NameId Int, Network VarChar(10) );
insert into @ValuesToAdd ( Name, NameId, Network ) values
  ( 'Nick', 4, 'RFGH' ), ( 'Tony', 3, 'ESLO' ),
  ( 'James', 2, 'HUII' ), ( 'Rusty', 3, 'ERNM' );
select * from @ValuesToAdd;

-- Process the data.
declare @Table4 as Table ( Id Int Identity, Name VarChar(10), NameId Int,
  NameFromId VarChar(10), Network VarChar(10) );
-- Demonstrate the matching.
select Name, NameId, NameFromId, Network
  from (
    select VTA.Name, VTA.NameId, N.Name as NameFromId, VTA.Network,
      Row_Number() over ( partition by VTA.Name order by NameRank, Id ) as RN
      from @ValuesToAdd as VTA inner join ( -- Use   left outer join   if there might not be a match on   NameId .
        select Id, Name, NameId, 1 as NameRank from @Table1 union all
        select Id, Name, NameId, 2 from @Table2 union all
        select Id, Name, NameId, 3 from @Table3 ) as N on N.NameId = VTA.NameId ) as PH
  --where RN = 1; -- Pick the match from the earliest table.
-- Insert the results.
insert into @Table4
  select Name, NameId, NameFromId, Network
    from (
      select VTA.Name, VTA.NameId, N.Name as NameFromId, VTA.Network,
        Row_Number() over ( partition by VTA.Name order by NameRank, Id ) as RN
        from @ValuesToAdd as VTA inner join ( -- Use   left outer join   if there might not be a match on   NameId .
          select Id, Name, NameId, 1 as NameRank from @Table1 union all
          select Id, Name, NameId, 2 from @Table2 union all
          select Id, Name, NameId, 3 from @Table3 ) as N on N.NameId = VTA.NameId ) as PH
    where RN = 1; -- Pick the match from the earliest table.
select * from @Table4;
```